# How to use a variable for mapReduce in MongoDB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of events that look like

```
{
  _id: BSONID
  name: "event_name",
  values: {a: 10, b: 1000, c: 50}
}
```

I'm trying to use mapReduce them using

```
map = function() {
  return emit([this.name, this.values['a']], this.values['b']);
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
  // stuff
}

collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: { inline: 1 } }, callback);
```

However, I would like to be able to dynamically change which values I map against. In essence, I'd like to have

```
var key = 'a';
var value = 'b';

map = function ()
{
  return emit([this.name, this.values[key]], this.values[value]);
}
```

The problem is that the execution context isn't passed to mongodb. Any solution that doesn't rely on using string for functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a "scope" variable to MapReduce:

```
scope = {key : "a", value : "b"};
collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {scope : scope, out: { inline: 1 } }, callback);
```

Comment: how can you reach the context inside ::map ? -> this.context ?